# How can i remove blank array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to Javascript.

Initial data:

```js
["Argentina", "Maroon 5:50<br>"]
["Australia", "Maroon 5:224<br>"]
["Austria", "Maroon 5:42<br>"]
["Belgium", "Maroon 5:10<br>"]
[""]
["Brazil", "Maroon 5:187<br>"]
[""]
["Canada", "Maroon 5:160<br>"]
[""]
["China", "Maroon 5:10<br>"]
[""]
[""]
[""]
[""]
[""]
[""]
[""]
[""]
["France", "Maroon 5:1533<br>"]
```

My code:

```js
     $.each(resp.result.artists_detail, function(index, item) {
  var arr = [];
  var pop_val = [];                       
  var artistdetails="";
  for (var i = 0; i < resp.result.artists.length; i++) {
    arr.push(item[0].country_name);
    if(item[i].play_count != 0){
      artistdetails +=item[i].artist_name +':'+ item[i].play_count+'<br>';
    }else{
      arr.pop(artistdetails);
    }  
  }
  arr.push(artistdetails);
  arrOfChart.push(arr);
});
```

I need this result:

```js
["Argentina", "Maroon 5:50<br>"]
["Australia", "Maroon 5:224<br>"]
["Austria", "Maroon 5:42<br>"]
["Belgium", "Maroon 5:10<br>"]
["Brazil", "Maroon 5:187<br>"]
["Canada", "Maroon 5:160<br>"]
["China", "Maroon 5:10<br>"]
["France", "Maroon 5:1533<br>"]
```

How can I remove blank arrays? I'm trying to add array for array push and remove array for array pop, but I need an array without a blank array.

Comment: which of the vars is the list?

Answer (score 1):

To remove empty values from array, you need to use `filter` function:

```
var array = [0, 1, null, 2, "", 3, undefined, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,];

var filtered = array.filter(function (el) {
  return el != "";
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

just do in the end:

```
arrOfChart = arrOfChart.filter(arr=>!(arr.length == 1 && arr[0] == ""))
console.log(arrOfChart)
>>>[
["Argentina", "Maroon 5:50<br>"],
["Australia", "Maroon 5:224<br>"],
["Austria", "Maroon 5:42<br>"],
["Belgium", "Maroon 5:10<br>"],
["Brazil", "Maroon 5:187<br>"],
["Canada", "Maroon 5:160<br>"],
["China", "Maroon 5:10<br>"],
["France", "Maroon 5:1533<br>"]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just use `filter`

```js
let data = [["Argentina", "Maroon 5:50<br>"],
["Australia", "Maroon 5:224<br>"],
["Austria", "Maroon 5:42<br>"],
["Belgium", "Maroon 5:10<br>"],
[""],
["Brazil", "Maroon 5:187<br>"],
[""],
["Canada", "Maroon 5:160<br>"],
[""],
["China", "Maroon 5:10<br>"],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
["France", "Maroon 5:1533<br>"]]

let result = data.filter(([el]) => el);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

by using `.filter` and implicit coercion of (`""` to `false`) you can achieve that

```
baseArray.filter( subArray => subArray[0]);
```

```js
const baseArray = [["Argentina", "Maroon 5:50<br>"],
["Australia", "Maroon 5:224<br>"],
["Austria", "Maroon 5:42<br>"],
["Belgium", "Maroon 5:10<br>"],
[""],
["Brazil", "Maroon 5:187<br>"],
[""],
["Canada", "Maroon 5:160<br>"],
[""],
["China", "Maroon 5:10<br>"],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
[""],
["France", "Maroon 5:1533<br>"]
];

const result = baseArray.filter( subArray => subArray[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @adirabargil we use [yagni](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html) principle;